# Is a HTTP request with request target to a proxy with query and fragment, a valid HTTP request?

Tags: java, regex, http

My goal is to validate HTTP request of the "request-line" e.g `GET http://www.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/uri/#Related HTTP/1.1`. Currently, I am validating the "request-target"

My reference is RFC7230. Unfortunately, RFC7230 does not specify the term of `absolute-form`, a new term from the documentation with a confusing reason because the documentation also state `absolute-form = absolute-uri`. So, I am not sure whether that is a valid `request-line`.

I am using a RegEx to validate the request target.

```
  static void parse(String requestTarget) throws HttpParsingException {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(requestTarget);
    if (!matcher.matches()) {
      throw new HttpParsingException(HttpStatusCode.CLIENT_ERROR_400_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
  }
```

The request target values are (expected to success)

```
GET http://www.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/uri/#Related HTTP/1.1
GET / HTTP/1.1
GET /where
GET /where?q=now
```

The request target values are (expected to fail)

```
GET // HTTP/1.1
GET  HTTP/1.1
```

The RegEx is from the Appendix B of [RFC3896]

Comment: This is not really a `[java]` question or a `[regex]` question.  It is actually about how the relevant RFCs specify the HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is a HTTP request with request target to a proxy with query and fragment, a valid HTTP request?

It is not valid.

The [HTTP Message Syntax and Message Routing RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-5.3) requires that the `request-target` URL in an HTTP request message is an `absolute-uri`.  (I see you have figured that out already ...)

If you track the `absolute-uri` term that back to its definition in the [URI RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-4.3), you will see that it means that a fragment is not allowed.  The URI RFC says:

> ### 4.3.  Absolute URI
>
> Some protocol elements allow only the absolute form of a URI without a
> fragment identifier.  For example, defining a base URI for later use
> by relative references calls for an absolute-URI syntax rule that does
> not allow a fragment.
>
> ```
> absolute-URI  = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ]
> ```

Note: that syntax does not allow a `fragment`.

---

I am not going to buy into the issue of writing regexes to do the URI parsing ... except to suggest that an alternative is to use the standard Java SE `URI` class.

Comment: I am assuming query is allowed within a request to a proxy?

Comment: Yes.  It is allowed.